# Interface designs of std::basic_fstream and std::unique_lock

Tags: c++, c++11, move, lazy-initialization

I'm comparing the two classes, because they both associate with something else. `std::basic_fstream` has to associate with a file, while `std::unique_lock` has to associate with a mutex. As such, providing an `open()` method seems reasonable. Still, `std::unique_lock` provides no such methods. Lazy initialization can be performed anyway via move assignment. It may thus seem redundant to provide an `open()` method. `std::basic_fstream`, on the other hand, does provide an `open()` method. `std::basic_fstream` exists before C++11, and it is the only way to perform lazy initialization then. Putting aside backward compatibility considerations, would `std::basic_fstream::open()` just be removed? Or it still needs to be there for the operation may fail actually? Note that, the open (associate) operation always succeeds with `std::unique_lock` (not to be confused with the lock operation).

Answer (score 1):

Your last sentence actually contains a hint: "`open` (associate) operation always succeeds with `std::unique_lock`". This makes it convenient to declare the open-ness as class invariant, establish it in the constructor and throw exceptions on rare failures. Compared that to files: Opening them can and does fail, so declaring open-ness as class invariant doesn't work as well there.

Comment: I don't think so. Although `std::unique_lock` provides no `open()` method, it does have a close one called `release()` that can change the open-ness, breaking the invariant.

Comment: You are right. Looking at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/unique_lock/unique_lock/, it seems that a `unique_lock` can have a reference to a mutex, but it doesn't have to have one, so you can open and close it like an `fstream`. Indeed, the only important difference is that it doesn't have a dedicated `open()` function but uses move semantics.